# ASP.NET website on a shared hosting featured on Mashable or Techcrunch

Tags: asp.net

assume the hypothetical case of a small ASP.NET website on a shared hosting (up to 250MB RAM) that is featured on a blog such as Mashable or Techcrunch (approx. 300K daily views).

Common sense tells me that it would have a severe impact on the website's response time and throughput, but I have no real experience.

Has anyone been in this situation before? Would the impact be so severe as I am thinking? Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not try and simulate it in a load test?

Comment: I did thought of that option but I do not want to get into trouble with my hosting company. Anyways what tools could you recommend me? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You will not get into trouble, they should have limits on your account that ifyou go overthe limit they will close the site down unless you upgrade your package. I know the test version of visual studio handled this not sure what else though, try google it.